# Getting value of NSCoding into string - KeychainWrapper

Tags: swift, nsarray, keychain

I am using KeychainWrapper to store a dictionary value however retrieving the items in a string value has come at a problem.

I've tried the following:

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.object(forKey: "userOptions").unsafelyUnwrapped
```

Which prints,

```
(
  (
    value,
    value, 
    value
  )
)
```

And

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.object(forKey: "userOptions").unsafelyUnwrapped as! [Any]
```

which prints

```
(
   value,
   value, 
   value
)
```

These methods above still appear to be impossible for me to retrieve the string only value from the NSCoding array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as,

```
let userOptions = (KeychainWrapper.standard.object(forKey: "userOptions").unsafelyUnwrapped as! [[String]]).joined().joined(separator: " ") )
```

Comment: Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x114dfde10) to 'NSString' (0x10fa0e4a8).

Comment: @JamesB What is the object type in that array?

Comment: `Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600003ca7b20>(
<__NSArrayI 0x6000031c9320>(
value,
value,
value)))`

Comment: Can you show how you are saving dictionary into Keychain?

Comment: `KeychainWrapper.standard.set(NSArray(object: ["value", "value", "value"]), forKey: "userOptions")`

Comment: @JamesB Can you try now?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!